# How to add date picker in Dialogflow bot! User have to select date by using javascript datepicker in nodejs

Tags: node.js, datepicker, dialogflow-es, chatbot, web-chat

I would like to inform you all, am using a Dialgflow chatbot, whereas the webchat is connected with the botframework, that is webchat UI is from bot-framework,  NLP is from Dialogflow.

I need an option for date picker where the user can select the date at one shot. Instead typing the date in the given format.

Can anyone let me know the procedure, how to add date picker in the dialogflow bot that too for webchat.

I have got the link from nodejs regarding js-datepicker...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker

Am okay with this npm but even if I use this, I need to know the procedure how to integrate with the dialogflow.

Am using fulfillment for dialogflow which is Nodejs.

Anyone help on this.

Let me know if any one has the clarifications.

REGARDS,
IMRANKHAN K

Comment: Any update,Suggestion on this above please.....

Answer (score 0):

I know is late but just in case.  If it is a webchat what you are using try www.kommunicate.io.  It has a webchat integration with dialogflow and a bunch of very interesting rich content including form with date picker and html.  [Kommunicate rich content docs](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/how-to-use-rich-messages)